# SOAP UI : Sending large string/content in rest request gives no response

Tags: rest, request, soapui

I have to test a `REST` `API` (`Post` & `HTTPS`) with different content lengths(`1KB-10MB`) for one particular parameter.

The intent for this API is to send a file. The `Rest` request works fine until I send a 1-5KB file.

But, beyond that request fails, actually it seems it was never was sent.  I see below in XML response and nothing under json

data contentType="null" contentLength="0">

I have already tried Content-Length in header &  increasing socket timeout

I have tried browser plugins also which also failed in sending large size string

Comment: `until I send a 1-5KB file`, a bit confused. You say you need to test from 1KB to 10MB, but that statement says it is failing form the start of the test.

Comment: What is in the log? What is in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same kind of problem.but I got my problem solved by groovy script for upload big file.Here is the code it may help you.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRoutePNames;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

String filename = "D:\\file.txt"

String hosts = "some-endpoint.com"
String resource = "resource/to/upload"

//Complete URL 
String url = "http://" + hosts + "/" + resource;
log.info(url)

File file = new File(filename); 
FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file, "text/plain"); 

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPut req = new HttpPut(url);

req.setHeader("header-key", "header-value");

// here set the file entity
req.setEntity(reqEntity);

//Declare HttpResposne object and intialize it to null
HttpResponse resp = null;

try {
    resp = client.execute(req);
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
log.info(resp);

HttpEntity entityNew = resp.getEntity();

System.out.println(resp.toString());

if(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        entityNew.writeTo(out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String str = new String(out.toByteArray());
    log.info(str);

    if(str.contains("some_text_in_response")){
        System.out.println("succ");
        assert true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Fail");
        assert false;
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println("Fail");
    assert false;
}
```

I have used HttpPut put you can HttpPost,HttpGet and other method classes refer apche http-client library docs